# Use autofilter on more than 2 criteria

Tags: vba, excel

How do you use VBA autofilter on more than 2 variables - I keep getting the error message:

> Named argument not found

Code below:

```
.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="HP Compaq 6000", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="HP Compaq 8000", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria3:="HP Compaq 8200", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria4:="HP Compaq 8200 Elite", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria5:="HP Compaq dc5800", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria6:="HP Compaq dc7900", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria7:="HP Compaq Elite 8300 SFF", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria8:="HP Compaq Pro 8300 SFF"
```

I would like to know if it is possible to filter data with more than 2 criteria in the same column using the AutoFilter. If there isn't, is there another way to accomplish this objective?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use this one instead:

```
.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("HP Compaq 6000", "HP Compaq 8000", _
                                    "HP Compaq 8200", "HP Compaq 8200 Elite", _
                                    "HP Compaq dc5800", "HP Compaq dc7900", _
                                    "HP Compaq Elite 8300 SFF", "HP Compaq Pro 8300 SFF"), _
                    Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: Is it possible to use wildcard matching when the Array() format is used?