# VBA Excel Macro Filtering

Tags: vba, excel

Getting Error 1004 
i want to filter on these 3 numbers in my macro.
2 numbers work okay, but when i add criteria 3 it breaks.
please help.

```
   ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$E").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= _
    "<>4649566", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:= _
    "<>7900559", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria3:= _
    "<>8910907", Operator:=xlAnd
```

Comment: A quick check on the MSDN page for `Range.Autofilter` seems to indicate that only two criteria are accepted: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: VBA wizard @simoco appears to have addressed a similar issue by using `Array()`, check the technique here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21834701/use-autofilter-on-more-than-2-criteria

Answer (score 1):

```
 ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$E").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= Array("<>4649566","<>7900559", "<>8910907"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```