# Excel VBA - filtering using an array, spaces and commas

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm having problems with autofilter in Excel VBA. I need to filter a column of cells containing text to display instances of "IT", but not words containing the letters "it" - i.e. I want to filter for cells containing "Commercial, IT" but not "Commercial, Committee".

I'm using an array as per this question: [Use autofilter on more than 2 criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21834701/use-autofilter-on-more-than-2-criteria)

It works when I use this code:

```
Worksheets("AssembledData").Range("A1").AutoFilter _
    field:=NewTeamCol, _
    Criteria1:=Array("IT", "IT, *"), _
    Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

But if I add a 3rd option to the array to catch cells where IT is at the end of the string `Criteria1:=Array("IT", "IT, *", "* IT"), _`, I get the same result as if I just had `Criteria1:=Array("IT"), _`

What am I doing wrong? New here, and new to VBA - done my best to search and not ask with this project, but stumped now! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot use wildcards in a wide array of filter criteria with `xlFilterValues`. If you do, then only the first two criteria from the array are considered; just as if you were using `Criteria1` and `Criteria2` with `Operator:=xlAnd`. The only option is to loop through the cells and build your own array of criteria into an array then submit that into the `.AutoFilter` command.

Comment: Thanks @Jeeped - that matches what I'm seeing. Guess I'll have to go build an array properly (or bodge it with row visibility...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always "filter by hand:"

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, v As String
    Dim r As Range
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To N
        Set r = Cells(i, "A")
        v = r.Text
        If Right(v, 3) = " IT" Or Left(v, 4) = "IT, " Or v = "IT" Then
            r.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            r.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! It works and I like 'handmade' code. Swapped the `left` and `right` bit for `If InStr(1, v, " IT", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Or InStr(1, v, "IT, ", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Or InStr(1, v, "IT ", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Or v = "IT" Then` to make sure all possible combinations of "IT" get picked up.

Answer (score 0):

Try omitting `Operator:=xlFilterValues`.

Since you are using wildcard characters along with xlFilterValues, Excel appears to compare literally `IT`, `IT, *` and `* IT` instead of using wildcard `*`.

For example, take this dataset:

```
   Name
1  john
2  nathjohn
3  test
4  abletest
5  testing
6  Commercial, IT
7  Commercial, Committee
8  IT, *
```

Using:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$15").AutoFilter _
        Field:=1, _
        Criteria1:=Array("IT", "IT, *", "* IT")
```

results in `Commercial, IT` because criteria's wildcards are correctly used with the exception of not choosing `IT, *`. Since that kind of value is not your immediate problem, we will conveniently skip over that corner case for now.

Using:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$15").AutoFilter _
    Field:=1, _
    Criteria1:=Array("IT", "IT, *", "* IT"), _
    Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

results in `IT, *` because xlFilterValues is using literal value of `IT, *`.

Give it a shot and see how things work.

Comment: Thanks. Tried it without `Operator:=xlFilterValues` but got no matches - wonder if I didn't apply your solution correctly? But @Jeeped's comment about wildcards suggests this might not be possible.