# Auto filter more than 2 or 3 Criteria

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Please help me out In the below code where I am trying to use more than 2 or 3 Criteria in Auto filter VBA code.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AH$122460").AutoFilter Field:=34, _
Criteria1:="<>#N/A", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="<>*n*", _
Operator:=xlOr, Criteria3:="=*b*"
```

OR

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AH$122460").AutoFilter Field:=34, _
Criteria1:="<>#N/A", Criteria2:="<>", Criteria3:="=*b*", Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

None of the above codes are working, please guide me how to deal while filtering the data with different criteria's.

Comment: Yes I want to filter cells that contain a "b" and also the other criteria along with the b is exists in my data. one think i want to share when i use only 2 criteria's as per the below code i.e. ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AH$122460").AutoFilter Field:=34, -
Criteria1:="<>#N/A", Criteria2:="=*b*", Operator:=xlFilterValues                     it's working fine only i got error while i entering 3 criteria.

Comment: try with 'macro recorder' to find out the proper solution. With `.Autofilter` you could use only two `.Criteria` parameters but one could be an array with multiple criteria. However, array is not working with all criteria types. Therefore try with macro recorder first to figure out the correct code. Alternatively, try with `Advanced filtering`...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21834701/use-autofilter-on-more-than-2-criteria

Comment: I have tried with Macro recorder as well but the recorded code contain the other criteria in array which is in-relevant for my coding as the other contain will change every time. is there any other way like using IfAnd condition or something.

Comment: _"as the other contain will change every time"_: you can fill an array with variables values. you may also want to give better detail about your exact filtering needs along with some examples

Comment: Respected Sir, my data contain different values every time for example: in Column "A" if A,B,C,D,#N/A   is available Next time when i received the data which might be contain A,E,F,G,B,#N/A in column "A", So simply I would like to ignore A,B,#N/A and filtered other values from the data.Therefore I couldn't define array with variables values because the other contain or Values will change every time when I receive the Data. Thus please help me out is there any way where I can use more then 2 criteria OR let me guide how can i use <> sign in array so the defined Values in array will be ignore.

Comment: so you _always_ want to _"ignore A,B,#N/A"_ values in column AH, no matter the data will be there, don't you?

Comment: Yes Sir, I always want to ignore A,B,#N/A values in column AH. Even the relevant data of these values are not require to me.Apart from those values other data i would like to use for my further working.

Comment: @sagar I am facing same issue tried using `Selection.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:=Array("<>A", "<>B", "<>C") Operator:=xlFilterValues. but it did not work.