# VBA skipping over a filter criteria

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I have the below code where I wish to use VBA to filter lists in Excel, Each list will be different depending on which company I select.

```
With wsDest.Rows(1)
.AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:="Swap", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="FwdSwap", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria3:="NDS"
  If wsDest.Range("C1:C" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count > 1 Then
  wsDest.Range("G2:G" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy wsDest.Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2)
     End If
.AutoFilter
End With
```

wsDest is the worksheet I am working in,  the code works fine except that lots of the lists i am filtering do not contain the "NDS" and the code breaks when this happens. Is there a way I can add into this 'if NDS exists in the list then use filter, else skip NDS as a filter'

Many thanks in advance

Comment: There is no `Criteria3` argument - see this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx. You might want to check this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21834701/use-autofilter-on-more-than-2-criteria. Not sure if its a duplicate.

Comment: Are you saying that the posted code works as long as there are entries for "NDS" in your data, and only crashes when there are no "NDS" entries in your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:="Swap", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="FwdSwap", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria3:="NDS"
```

Your syntax here is incorrect for filtering on multiple criteria. Although there is a `Criteria2`, there is no `Criteria3` and so on for this method.

Where you want to filter for multiple values, you should instead use an array with `Criteria1`:

```
.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Array("Swap", "FwdSwap", "NDS"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Also note the change in Operator to `xlFilterValues` as pointed out by @YowE3K