# How to filter multiple data using keywords in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, filter, criteria

I want to filter out the unnecessary data with these 3 keywords: Proton, Hyundai, Perodua. But I am getting the "Named argument not found" error after I run this code.

```
''Filtering return reason for Sheet1
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter

Dim rng As Range

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:L2671")
FilterField = WorksheetFunction.Match("Car", rng.Rows(1), 0)

'Turn on filter if not already turned on
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False Then rng.AutoFilter

'Filter Specific Countries
rng.AutoFilter Field:=FilterField, Criteria1:="=*Proton*" _
    , Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=*Hyundai*" _
    , Operator:=xlOr, Criteria3:="=*Perodua*"
```

The Criteria3 was highlighted after I ran this code. Why can't I insert the 3 criteria onto the filter filed?

Here's the example of my data:

[image: Sample]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use autofilter on more than 2 criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21834701/use-autofilter-on-more-than-2-criteria)

Comment: @RobinMackenzie this link using the array. How do I using the array together with the keywords to search?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Auto Filtering multiple wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602872/set-auto-filtering-multiple-wildcards)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if autofilter can take more than 2 criteria as given in [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/range-autofilter-method-excel)

However, you may want to try passing an array into criteria1 as proposed in another solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21834701/use-autofilter-on-more-than-2-criteria)

Personally, I would prefer to use helper columns with functions (e.g. if statements) to narrow down my selection before using autofilter.

Comment: But if I am using array, I need to write down all type of cars from these 3 car brands. Is there any better suggestion?

Comment: @Icc yea that's the problem with this solution. As I am unsure of your exact conditions, at this point, I would think something along the lines of creating a helper column `=if(find("Hyundai",A1)>0, 1 , 0)` and filtering the helper column to obtain the results that you want. Do let me know if this helps.

Comment: It's really helpful but time-consuming though. Anyway, I appreciate for your kind help. :)

Comment: @Icc actually you will probably have to write the formula only once and drag it down since finding Hyundai will essentially be similar to your original "*Hyundai*" - meaning it should capture the different models by Hyundai, you don't actually have to include every model in the formula

Comment: Yup, I knew this function. But my "client" prefer all task is being automated which mean he only need to click one button that assigned with macro and all the tasks will perform automatically.

Comment: you will be able to use VBA to process the entire column without using autofilter but either way, it will still require your client to first determine the brand of the car that he is interested in. You may want to consider allowing your client to input the desired brands in a certain range and then using those inputs to pick up the relevant cells using VBA. in VBA, `InStr` is equivalent to `find`

Comment: I suddenly come out with this solution. First, I filter these two criteria out.
`rng.AutoFilter Field:=FilterField, Criteria1:="=*Proton*" _
    , Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=*Hyundai*"`
After I delete the unwanted data, then I filter again the next criteria out to delete.

Comment: yea sounds viable..just do note that vba speed is partly determined by the number of times the code "hits" the worksheet and using autofilter will likely be slower if u were to process the options in your code. However, if speed isnt your concern, please ignore the above. Congrats on your solution!

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs because of using Wildcards. In those cases you can not use more than 2 filter values at the same time.

This doesn't work:

```
rng.AutoFilter Field:=FilterField, _
    Criteria1:=Array("*Hyundai*","*Proton*","*Perodua*"), _
    Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

However, you could use pattern matching by first getting your range to be filtered in an array and dynamically create the values to be filtered array.

Good sample code is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602872/set-auto-filtering-multiple-wildcards/34822944#34822944)