# Excel VBA to filter 2 columns

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible that it will filter 2 columns? Like it will filter country and date (which are less than today's date) or if possible it will filter only the highlighted cell on the second filter. Thank you. Btw, I'm using Ron de Bruin codes, copyrights to him.

Example of what I'm looking:[sample excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsmBc.jpg)

```
Sub Send_Row_Or_Rows_2()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim rng As Range
Dim Ash As Worksheet
Dim Cws As Worksheet
Dim Rcount As Long
Dim Rnum As Long
Dim FilterRange As Range
Dim FieldNum As Integer

On Error GoTo cleanup
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

'Set filter sheet, you can also use Sheets("MySheet")
Set Ash = ActiveSheet

'Set filter range and filter column (column with e-mail addresses)
Set FilterRange = Ash.Range("A1:H" & Ash.Rows.Count)
FieldNum = 3 'Filter column = B because the filter range start in column A

'Add a worksheet for the unique list and copy the unique list in A1
Set Cws = Worksheets.Add
FilterRange.Columns(FieldNum).AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CopyToRange:=Cws.Range("A1"), _
        CriteriaRange:="", Unique:=True

'Count of the unique values + the header cell
Rcount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cws.Columns(1))

'If there are unique values start the loop
If Rcount >= 2 Then
    For Rnum = 2 To Rcount

        'Filter the FilterRange on the FieldNum column
        FilterRange.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, _
                               Criteria1:=Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value

        'If the unique value is a mail addres create a mail
        'If Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then

            With Ash.AutoFilter.Range
                On Error Resume Next
                Set rng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                On Error GoTo 0
            End With

            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Offest(0, 1).Value
                .Subject = "Test mail"
                .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
                .Display  'Or use Send
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0

            Set OutMail = Nothing


        'Close AutoFilter
        Ash.AutoFilterMode = False

    Next Rnum
End If
```

Comment: what is the error that you are facing? where have you tried to modify?

Comment: It is working as of the moment with only one column filtered. But I'm looking for a way, if possible, that it can filter 2 columns.

Comment: you may want to try the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21834701/use-autofilter-on-more-than-2-criteria

Comment: Hmm. Looks fine but not what I need. I need to filter another column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you filter once using

```
FilterRange.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, _
                           Criteria1:=Cws.Cells(Rnum, 1).Value
```

all you have to do to filter it further is write another analogous statement after that:

```
FilterRange.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum2, _
                           Criteria1:= 'your criteria
```

If you do so, it will be filtered on both chosen columns. Same goes for three, four, or multiple other filters on the same dataset.

Comment: Thanks for this but not working. Only the headers comes out.

Comment: This happens when your criteria is not right for the job. What is your second criteria?

Comment: My second criteria will filter out the date that are < (less than) today's date or if possible the highlighted cell.

Comment: Then you should write
`FilterRange.AutoFilter Field:='your field number, _
                           Criteria1:="<" & date`
or
`FilterRange.AutoFilter Field:='your field number, _
                           Criteria1:="<" & selection`

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your help. Cheers!