# What is table filtered criteria? (As one of or array of choosen values from column header drop-down list of Table)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Table with multiple columns that has auto filtering.

One of my columns, has month auto filtering, which taking in bellow code.

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Salary").Range.AutoFilter Field:= _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Mounth", Range("Salary[#Headers]"), 0), _
    Criteria1:="=09"
```

Sometimes I need give filtering criteria value of that column an assign to variable. So always not known about what is the filtered value.

Of course user may select more than one items from table header menu drop-down list, as act of code below:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Salary").Range.AutoFilter Field:= _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Mounth", Range("Salary[#Headers]"), 0), _
    Criteria1:="=09", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=08"
```

How can catch all selected ones in an array or sure if the selected value is unique and assigning that to a same variable?

Comment: The answer was post with [`Scott Holtzman`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1569536/scott-holtzman) so deleted his answer because the question scope extended and updating. He introduced a [reference](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/autofilter-criteria.htm) that involved exact and useful true answer. with best regard and thanks for him.

Comment: And to choose [multiple criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21835032/7690982) on Autofilter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.AutoFilter.Filters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/autofilter-filters-property-excel) can be used to get the filter values:

```
Dim list As ListObject, colIndex As Long, filter As Filter
Set list = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
If list.ShowAutoFilter = False Then Exit Sub   ' filters are not on

colIndex = list.ListColumns("Month").Index
Set filter = list.AutoFilter.filters(colIndex)
If filter.On = False Then Exit Sub             ' no filter

Select Case filter.Operator
    Case 0:        Debug.Print filter.Criteria1                   ' no operator
    Case xlOr:     Debug.Print filter.Criteria1, filter.Criteria2
    Case xlValues: Debug.Print Join(filter.Criteria1)             ' array
    Case Else: Debug.Print filter.Operator, filter.Criteria1, filter.Criteria2 ' handle the rest of the operators
End Select
```