# Inserting data from web to excel sheet - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need to insert data from xls file from web, to my current opened workbook. The problem is that if I run this macro several time, it always create new sheet. Ideally I would like to delete old content and replaced it with new content on same sheet. It is possible? Here is my code

```
Sub downloadData()

Dim wkbMyWorkbook As Workbook
Dim wkbWebWorkbook As Workbook
Dim wksWebWorkSheet As Worksheet
Dim currentDate As Date

Set wkbMyWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook

currentDate = Date

Workbooks.Open ("https://www.somewebpage.com/file.xls")

Set wkbWebWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set wksWebWorkSheet = ActiveSheet

wksWebWorkSheet.Copy After:=wkbMyWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)

wkbMyWorkbook.Activate
wkbWebWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the sheet dumped from the web will always be the last sheet in the workbook, use this line:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wkbMyWorkbook.Worksheets(wkbMyWorkbook.Worksheets.Count).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

before copying new sheet.

Comment: I get error and it opens downloaded file in new workbook: Run time error '1004' Delete method of Worksheet class failed.

Comment: @joe32 - try now. I fully qualified objects

Comment: @Scott Holtzman Please take a loot at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46329608/what-is-table-filtered-criteria-as-one-of-or-array-of-choosen-values-from-colu/46329835?noredirect=1#comment79655687_46329835)

Comment: @Scott Holtzman Please take a loot at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46329608/what-is-table-filtered-criteria-as-one-of-or-array-of-choosen-values-from-colu/46329835?noredirect=1#comment79655687_46329835) I owe you this result. Please publish that useful reference as an answer.

Comment: @MGae2M - I appreciate your sentiment and saw your comment. I will keep answer deleted since there is so much back and forth in the comments and the answer I actually did provide is not accurate to the problem.

Comment: @Scott Holtzman [this](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/autofilter-criteria.htm) reference that you tell, is the answer. It can published under [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46329608/what-is-table-filtered-criteria-as-one-of-or-array-of-choosen-values-from-colu/46329835?noredirect=1#comment79655687_46329835) answer. with great thanks.