# Excel VBA - find one cell and return other values in that row to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that I am using to find rejections for jobs per manufacturer.

So far I have code to find all the manufacturers and remove duplicates.
Problem is i need to find only the rejected jobs and values then compose a list and sum manufacturers together.

I know a little bit of VBA and this is a bit over my head but would really like to see it.

[Link to example data in google sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mUjytrE7CLcPfhxWoRO8aTiT_IMy59ZPgKjcAk3kdl8/edit?usp=sharing)

---

```
Sub Make_Defect_List()
    '=====================================================================================
    'Problems
    'Look for reject in all data
    'Return cells D/count and K/Manufacturer
    'Simplify by combining manufacturer and adding numbers based on manufacturer
    'Sort and make chart

    Dim label As String, i, x, tbl_row_count As Integer
    Dim label_range, table_range As String
    Set shVP = Sheets("VendorProblems")
    Set shAD = Sheets("AllData")
    lr = shVP.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = shVP.Range("A2" & lr)
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''Finds all vendors and pastes on other sheet
    ''works
    ''needs to be by rejected
    x = 1
    If shAD.Range("K2") <> "" Then
        For i = 1 To shAD.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            shVP.Range("A" & 1 + x) = shAD.Range("K" & 1 + i)
            x = x + 1
        Next i
    Else: End If
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''Removes Duplicates
    ''Works
    shVP.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''Sorts A-Z
    ''Works
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("VP").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("VP").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), SortOn _
        :=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("VP").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A:A")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''Deletes blank cells
    ''Works
    rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
End Sub
```

Comment: your Raw Data image points to a blank image.

Comment: Big thanks to anyone that can help sort me out lol.

Comment: Yea sorry dont know why it did that. If you look at the sheets link i shared its the same as the image.

Comment: You could .Autofilter for "Reject" Value on column H. Then make a match for each Manufacturer. Or loop through an [autofilter with multicriteria](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21835032/7690982) thatchanges the criteria for manufacturer name, until the last one.

Comment: I will give it a try. Have never used .autofilter so im gonna play around with it a bit. Thank you danieltakeshi!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expects the data you provided, in tab **AllData**, and another tab called **VendorProblems**

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Make_Defect_List1()
    Const REJECTED_COL = 8          'Column H (DISPOSITIO)
    Dim shAD As Worksheet, shVP As Worksheet, adRng As Range, vpRng As Range, flg As Byte

    Set shAD = Worksheets("AllData")
    Set shVP = Worksheets("VendorProblems")

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    shAD.AutoFilterMode = False     'Copy VendorProblems to shVP --------------------------
    With shAD.UsedRange
        Set adRng = FilterWS(.Columns(REJECTED_COL), "Reject")
        If Not adRng Is Nothing Then
            If .Cells.CountLarge > 2 Then
                Set vpRng = shVP.Cells(shVP.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
                .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Copy vpRng
            End If
        End If
    End With
    shAD.AutoFilterMode = False
    shVP.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo    'Removes Dupes ------------
    Set vpRng = shVP.UsedRange.Columns(1)
    With shVP.Sort          'Sort shVP ----------------------------------------------------
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SetRange shVP.UsedRange
        .SortFields.Add Key:=vpRng, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .Apply
    End With
    With shVP.UsedRange     'Remove blanks from shVP --------------------------------------
        shVP.AutoFilterMode = False
        If Len(shVP.Cells(1)) = 0 Then shVP.Cells(1) = "Header": flg = 1
        Set vpRng = FilterWS(shVP.UsedRange.Columns(1), "=")
        If Not vpRng Is Nothing Then
            Set vpRng = shVP.UsedRange.Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            If .Cells.Count > 1 Then .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
        If flg = 1 Then shVP.Cells(1).EntireRow.Delete
        shVP.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Function FilterWS(ByRef filtrRng As Range, filtrBy As String) As Range

    If filtrRng Is Nothing Or Len(filtrBy) = 0 Then Set FilterWS = Cells(1): Exit Function

    filtrRng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=filtrBy
    Set FilterWS = filtrRng.Parent.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

End Function
```

Comment: Having a problem with the FilterWS command. Im using Excel 2010.

Comment: Can you provide any details about the problem? what exactly is it and what line generates it? (for `adRng`, or `vpRng`?). Do you have the data on sheet "AllData", and do you have another empty sheet called VendorProblems?. Also in your initial code there is a reference to a 3rd sheet called `Worksheets("VP")`. Is that different than "VendorProblems"? if so, what's its purpose?