# How do you use VBA to filter for multiple criteria in a single column in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I expected the code below to work because it came from [a well-rated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21834701/use-autofilter-on-more-than-2-criteria).

If this is a formatting error I would like to correct the error rather than completely changing the approach of the solution. If this way of doing things will not work at all then I am open to trying different approaches.

Any insights would be much appreciated!

```
 ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$AI").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=Array("Namib", "Kitchen", _
                            "Constantia", "Painters", _
                            "CUSTOM", "Classic", _
                            "Bench"), _
            Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: what's the issue you meet with your code?

Comment: For me, your code works. However, are you sure you are dealing with `ActiveSheet` all the time?

Comment: Okay, thanks for the support here,Looking deeper into this I realized that what I actually want is a filter that will filter out all cells CONTAINING the words in my list.

i.e. If the filter values that I present are `Table`, `Chair` and `Couch` ; then I want to see a list of all the different tables, chairs and couches.

Visually:

Small Table
Medium Table
Large Table
Something Else
Small Chair
Another undesired product
Big Couch
Some Junk

Reduces to:

Small Table
Medium Table
Large Table
Small Chair
Big Couch

Answer (score 0):

You can only filter 2 criteria with wildcards:

```
Range("$A:$AI").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="=*Table*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=*Chair*"
```

Will filter all data containing the word `Table` or `Chair`. But this does not work for more than 2 criteria.

```
'THIS DOES NOT WORK:
Range("$A:$AI").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=Array("*Namib*", "*Kitchen*", _
   "*Constantia*", "*Painters*", _
   "*CUSTOM*", "*Classic*", _
   "*Bench*"), _
     Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

See: [Set Auto Filtering multiple wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602872/set-auto-filtering-multiple-wildcards/34822944#34822944) for a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another workaround:

```
Sub FilterMultipleWildcards()
    Dim myCriteria As Variant, criterium As Variant
    Dim filteredRng As Range

    myCriteria = Array("Namib", "Kitchen", "Constantia", "Painters", "CUSTOM", "Classic", "Bench")

    With ActiveSheet
        With Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("$A:$AI"))
            Set filteredRng = .Offset(, .Columns.Count).Resize(1, 1)
            For Each criterium In myCriteria
                .AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="=*" & criterium & "*"
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(1)) > 1 Then Set filteredRng = Union(filteredRng, .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 10).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
            Next
            Set filteredRng = Intersect(filteredRng, .Cells)
            .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
            .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End With
        filteredRng.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End With
End Sub
```

whose limitation resides in the "capacity" of the range resulting from `Union()` method