# VBA - How to AutoFilter on same field for more than two criteria?

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I've been searching for an answer all day and can't seem to find a solution to my issue. The closest thing I found to my problem is this link right here:

[Use autofilter on more than 2 criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21834701/use-autofilter-on-more-than-2-criteria)

This is my worksheet:

[image: My Worksheet]

That, however, doesn't solve my problem. I've been using the answer from that question as a basis in my searching. I'm not getting any errors, but when I run the code it filters out rows 6-35 (the whole thing!).

```
Dim calc as Worksheet
Dim lastrow as Integer

Set calc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Calc")
lastrow = Application.CountA(Range("A6:A" & Rows.Count)) + 5

calc.Range("A5:T" & lastrow).AutoFilter _
     Field:=4, _
     Criteria1:=Array(3410, 3420, 3440, 3450, 3490, 1445), _
     Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

I've also tried the same code but without the "Operator" part of it and it actually filters for the two rows (rows 6 and 20) with the last criteria in the Array (1445). But why not for the rest? I'm so lost and I've been searching for hours. I feel like this SHOULD be straight forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use quotes for numbers.
The other problem with your code is that you define last row on *active* sheet and this sheet can happen to be not `calc` sheet. Precede your references with `calc.`.

Comment: Hey JohnyL, I don't think that's what I'm looking for here. I tested it anyway though (just in case) and I get the same result as before.

Comment: What is the value of `lastrow`?

Comment: the value of lastrow is 35.

Comment: @AP1 Wrote a solution