# Adding a third criteria to autofilter VBA

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I would like to add an additional 3rd criteria to the code i wrote that autofilters the values "RENT" and "emprent" in the set range. I would like to add "rtna" as the third criteria.

```
Sheets("Filter").Activate
With ActiveSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("P1:W10000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array("RENT", "rtna", _
                                    "emprent"), _
                    Operator:=xlFilterValues
End With
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use autofilter on more than 2 criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21834701/use-autofilter-on-more-than-2-criteria)

Comment: @BigBen I tried that method and it did not seem to work for me.

Comment: you could move to a multi key sort . . . if it suits your purposes.

Comment: [`Range.Autofilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter) doesn't have a 3rd criterion. Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52189466/edit) your question with the attempt to use an `Array` like in the linked question?

Comment: @BigBen see edit above.

Comment: `Field` should be 5 based on your original code, right?

Comment: @BigBen yes it should